# How do you work out what's making up the total CPU% on Linux?

Tags: gjs, htop, ubuntu-21.04

My fan is whirring on my Ubuntu laptop and `htop` is showing my CPU as maxed:

[image: CPU]

However, looking at the processes ordered by CPU it doesn't seem like too much is going on other than `gjs` at 41.3%.

[image: Processes ordered by CPU]

I'm assuming there are just a ton of `gjs` processes that are adding up to the rest of the CPU.

Is there anyway to work this out other than manually adding up the CPU%?

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="21.10"
```

Comment: Hey, I don't think I've been awarded the bounty yet, since you accepted my answer in the grace period where you need to award it manually. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sum up CPU usage as shown [here](https://superuser.com/a/1530439).

```sh
ps -eo pcpu,command --sort=-pcpu | grep gjs | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'
```

The solution they linked actually sums memory, not CPU usage (probably a bug they never caught), I've fixed it so it should work for you.

If you want to make a shell script to reuse, write this to `cpusum` for example:

```sh
ps -eo pcpu,command --sort=-pcpu | grep "$1" | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'
```

then make it executable: `chmod +x cpusum`,
and run it `./cpusum gjs`